# Finding a passcode by comparing MD5 result

Tags: scala, hashcode

This function finds the 8 char passcode from a given "doorId".

Is there a way to find the passcode in an undetermined number of steps without using a `while`? Maybe involving streams? `val passcode = stream(logic).take(8)`.

```
def findPassCode(doorId: String): String = {
  var passcode = ""
  var count = 0

  while (passcode.length < 8) {
    val hash = md5(doorId + count)
    if (hash.startsWith("00000")) passcode = passcode + hash.drop(5).take(1)
    count = count + 1
  }

  passcode
}
```

Comment: This code appears to be for [2016 Advent of Code, Day 5](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/5). It would be nice if you would include such contextual information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have the `passcode` length hard-coded.  It would be better to make it a parameter, perhaps with a default value.  The same goes for the string the "interesting" hashes start with (`"00000"`).

Also, there are several ways you could make the code more functional.  Here are a couple ideas:

- Use recursion:  Computing an \$n\$ character pascode is accomplished by first computing an \$n-1\$ character passcode, then computing the next character.  Or, you could rewrite the loop in a tail-recursive form.
- You could use [streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html).  Streams are Scala's version of a lazy list / sequence.

Using streams, we can use the following logic:

1. Generate a stream of consecutive `Int`s, starting at `0`.
2. Combine each number in with `doorId`
3. Compute the hash of each combined string
4. Filter the hashes, keeping only hashes that start with five `'0'`s
5. Take the sixth character of each hash
6. Take the first `8 - doorId.length` characters, and append them to `doorId`

We can express this in code using something like:

```
def findPassCode(doorId: String): String = {
  val chars = Stream.from(0)                            // Step 1
                    .map(n => doorId + n)               // Step 2
                    .map(md5)                           // Step 3
                    .filter(h => h.startsWith("00000")) // Step 4
                    .map(h => h(5))                     // Step 5
  doorId + chars.take(8 - doorId.length).mkString       // Step 6
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful! I always want to take 8 characters from the stream. Thats the nature of the passcode. So what I want is simply `doorId + chars.take(8).mkString`. Your code worked without other modifications! Really happy to get rid of the loop and conditionals. They are festering grounds of bugs.

Comment: @RedMercury, ah yes, I think I misunderstood exactly what the `passcode` was supposed to be slightly.  Glad you found it useful, though.  You're right about looping (and explicit recursion) -- it should be avoided if possible.  I agree that hard-coding for 8 characters is ok for a simple exercise.  But remember people tend to do as they practice -- so it's better to always practice best practices (at least to a point).

Comment: The implementation could be simplified further as `Stream.from(0).map(n => md5(doorId + n)).filter(_.startsWith("00000")).map(_(5)).take(8).mkString`.

Comment: I found that the functional solution using a `Stream`, though more elegant, performed much poorer than the original code.